# How to define three way many to many relationshop in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm having a hard time creating a three way many to many relationship between three tables/models in Laravel 5. And so far looking up from the web hasn't given me any workable solution.

I have three models: **User**, **Role**, **Thesis**.

What I would like to achieve is to connect the three with each other. For example a **user** can be associated with many **theses** and this **user** can have many different **roles** on one specific **thesis**.

So a **user** can have many roles (instructor and reviewer for example) on one specific **thesis** and the same **user** can also be associated with another **thesis** and having another **role** on that as well (for example instructor only).

So far I've tried an approach which means creating another model that would handle the pivot table. So I created a model **Relation**.

Tables I have at the moment:

**users**

```
id 
name
```

**theses**

```
id 
topic
```

**roles**

```
id 
name
```

**relations**

```
id
role_id (references id on roles) 
thesis_id (references id on theses)
user_id (references id on users)
```

And the **code** I have right now

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function relations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Relation', 'relations');
    }
}
```

**Thesis.php**

```
class Thesis extends Model
{
    public function relations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Relation', 'relations');
    }
}
```

**Role.php**

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function relations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Relation', 'relations');
    }
}
```

**Relation.php**

```
class Relation extends Model
{
    public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function thesis(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thesis');
    }

    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Right now I'm using **$relation = new Relation;** approach when inserting into the pivot table.

I don't know how I can get the data from the pivot table. For example get **thesis** of **user** and what kind of **roles** the **user** has on that specific **thesis**.

I've tried something like **$user->thesis()** or **$user->role()** or **$user->thesis()->role()** but none of them don't work. I'm only getting an undefined method error.

I would really appreciate if I could get some help or at least some kind of direction if even what I've showed here is somewhat correct.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're interested in a [Many to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) which stores the relationship through an intermediate table. An intermediate table can have additional attributes stored on it, therefore, you can create a `thesis_users` intermediate table with an additional `role_id` attribute. The documentation covers this use case under the heading "Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns". You do not need an additional model to represent these relationships.

You can query the intermediate table (also referred to as a `pivot table`) if you need to determine which `Thesis` a user has specific `roles` on, e.g:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thesis')->wherePivot('role_id', 1);
```

Your User model relationship would look something like this:

```
public function theses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thesis');
}
```

Your Thesis model relationship would look something like this:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Then you can do additional relationship constraints on your Thesis model, like this:

```
public function authors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->wherePivot('role_id', 1);
}


public function reviewers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->wherePivot('role_id', 2);
}


public function instructors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->wherePivot('role_id', 3);
}
```

And on your User model like this:

```
public function authored()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thesis')->wherePivot('role_id', 1);
}

public function reviewer()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thesis')->wherePivot('role_id', 2);
}
```

etc.

```
Thesis::find(1)->reviewers(); // returns every App\User with the role_id 2 on App\Thesis with ID 1
Thesis::find(1)->instructors(); // returns every App\User with the role_id 3 on App\Thesis with ID 1

User::find(1)->theses(); // returns each App\Thesis that the user has any role on 
User::find(1)->authored(); // returns each App\Thesis that the user has the author role on
```

Comment: Yeah this should work as expected. Thanks!
But how can I insert these three values (role_id, thesis_id, user_id) into the pivot with the attach() method? I know how to do that with two attributes but is there a way for three attributes as well using attach()?

Comment: You can pass a second paramter to `attach`, which is an array of additional data, see the documntation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many under "Attaching / Detaching" :)

Answer (score 1):

I had done some work around. Created a new relationship. [This](http://www.aimme.xyz/2018/01/laravel-many-to-many-many-tthrough-many.html) might help you. I have copy pasted the same code here.

> It might not be the best performance wise.

**First Scenario - Belongs to many through many**

Example

user belongs to many roles

roles belongs to many users

roles belongs to many permissions

permissions belongs to many roles

```
users → user-role → roles → role-permission→ permissions
```

5 tables (2 pivots)

So, Lets say we want to fetch a users permissions, which are connected through roles

```
 //attach roles to user
$user->roles()->attach($admin->id);

//attach permissions to user
$admin->permissions()->attach($permission->id);

//get users' permissions using HasManyThroughMany relationship

$userPermissions = $user->permissions();
```

User.php

```
use App\Extensions\Eloquent\Model as Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function permissions()
    {        
        return $this->hasManyThroughMany(Permission::class,
           Role::class,
           'user_role',
           'role_permission',
           'permission_id',
           'role_id');
    }
}
```

Role.php

```
class Role extends Model
{ 
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_role', 'role_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'role_permission', 'role_id', 'permission_id');
    }
}
```

Permission.php

```
class Permission extends Model
{  
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class ,'user_permission', 'permission_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_permission', 'permission_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

**Second Scenario - Has many through many**

Example

student has many enrollments

each enrollment has many subjects

each subject belongs to an enrollment

each enrollment belongs to a student

```
student→ enrollment → subject
```

3 tables

So, Lets say we want to fetch a students subjects, which are connected through enrollments

```
//save students enrollment
$student->enrollments()->save($enrollment);

//save enrollments subject
$enrollment->subjects()->save($subject);

//get student's subjects using HasManyThroughMany relationship
$student->subjects();
```

Student.php

```
use App\Extensions\Eloquent\Model as Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    public function enrollments()
    {
     return $this->hasMany(Enrollment::class);
    }

    public function subjects()
    {
     return $this->hasManyThroughMany(Subject::class, Enrollment::class);
    }
}
```

Enrollment.php

```
class Enrollment extends Model
{
    public function subjects()
    {
     return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
    }

    public function student()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
    }
}
```

Subject.php

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    public function enrollment()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo(Enrollment::class);
    }
}
```

New HasManyThroughMany relationship file.

HasManyThroughMany.php

```
namespace App\Extensions\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as EloquentModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class HasManyThroughMany extends Relation
{
    public function __construct(
  Builder $query,
  EloquentModel $farParent,
  EloquentModel $parent,
  $firstKey, $secondKey,
  $localKey,
  $throughKey)
    {
        $this->localKey = $localKey;
        $this->firstKey = $firstKey;
        $this->secondKey = $secondKey;
        $this->farParent = $farParent;
        $this->throughKey = $throughKey;
        $this->farParentRelatedKey = $this->getModelRelatedKey($this->farParent);
        parent::__construct($query, $parent);
    }

    public function addConstraints()
    {
        $parentTable = $this->parent->getTable();

        $this->setJoin();
        if (static::$constraints && !$this->throughKey) {
            $localValue = $this->farParent[$this->localKey];
            $this->query->where($parentTable.'.'.$this->firstKey, '=', $localValue);
        } else {
            $localValue = $this->farParent['id'];
            $this->query->where($this->firstKey . '.' . $this->farParentRelatedKey, '=', $localValue);
        }

    }

    protected function setJoin(Builder $query = null)
    {

        $query = $query ?: $this->query;

        $foreignKey = $this->related->getTable().'.'.$this->secondKey;
        $farParentTable = $this->farParent->getTable();
        $farParentTableKey = $farParentTable.'.'.$this->localKey;
        $firstKey = $this->parent->getTable().'.'.$this->firstKey;

        $id = $this->related->getTable() . '.id as id';
        $all = $this->related->getTable() . '.*';
        $columns = [$id, $all];
        if(!$this->throughKey){
            $query->addSelect($columns)
   ->join($this->parent->getTable(),
     $this->getQualifiedParentKeyName(),
     '=',
     $foreignKey)
            ->join($farParentTable,
     $farParentTableKey,
     '=',
     $firstKey);
        } else {
            $query->addSelect($columns)
            ->join($this->secondKey,
     $this->secondKey . '.' . $this->localKey,
     '=',
     $this->related->getTable() . '.id')
            ->join($this->firstKey,
     $this->firstKey . '.' . $this->throughKey,
     '=',
     $this->secondKey . '.' . $this->throughKey)
            ->join($farParentTable,
     $farParentTable . '.id',
     '=',
     $this->firstKey . '.' . $this->farParentRelatedKey);
        }
        if ($this->parentSoftDeletes()) {
            $query->whereNull($this->parent->getQualifiedDeletedAtColumn());
        }

    }

    public function getModelRelatedKey($model)
    {
        return strtolower(class_basename($model)) . '_id';
    }

    public function getForeignKey()
    {
        return $this->related->getTable().'.'.$this->secondKey;
    }

    public function parentSoftDeletes()
    {
        return in_array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes',
      class_uses_recursive(get_class($this->parent)));
    }

    public function addEagerConstraints(array $models){}
    public function initRelation(array $models, $relation)
    {
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $model->setRelation($relation, $this->related->newCollection());
        }

        return $models;
    }
    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation){}
    public function getResults()
    {
        return $this->get();
    }    
}
```

New Model file
Model.php

```
namespace Hello\Extensions\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model AS EloquentModel;
use App\Extensions\Eloquent\HasManyThroughMany;

class Model extends EloquentModel
{
    public function hasManyThroughMany($related,
            $through,
            $firstKey = null,
            $secondKey = null,
            $localKey = null,
            $throughKey = null)
    {
        $through = new $through;

        $firstKey = $firstKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $secondKey = $secondKey ?: $through->getForeignKey();

        $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

        return new HasManyThroughMany((new $related)->newQuery(),
          $this,
          $through,
          $firstKey,
          $secondKey,
          $localKey,
          $throughKey);

    }

}
```